# how to get microsoft edge chromium version from command line or registry settings

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium

I have to automate getting edge chromium browser version in python. I tried the registry settings mentioned in this HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge

.But that registry key is not present.

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve Microsoft Edge Chromium version programmatically: from **Windows Registry** or **Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) Database**

Let's start with command line versions:

**Registry** (Method 1)

```
reg.exe QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon" /t REG_SZ /reg:32 /v version
```

**Registry** (Method 2)

```
reg.exe QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{56EB18F8-B008-4CBD-B6D2-8C97FE7E9062}" /t REG_SZ /reg:32 /v pv
```

**WMI** (Method 3)

```
wmic.exe DATAFILE WHERE "NAME='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe'" GET Version /value
```

Here's a simple Python script for retrieving the version from **Registry** (using `winreg` module) and **WMI** (by calling `wmic.exe` and parsing its output)

```
import subprocess
import winreg
import re

# ----- Method 1 -----
keyPath1 = r"Software\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon"
key1 = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyPath1, 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
edgeVersion1 = winreg.QueryValueEx(key1, "version")[0]

print(f'Method #1 >>> {edgeVersion1}')

# ----- Method 2 -----
keyPath2 = r"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{56EB18F8-B008-4CBD-B6D2-8C97FE7E9062}"
key2 = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyPath2, 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
edgeVersion2 = winreg.QueryValueEx(key2, "pv")[0]

print(f'Method #2 >>> {edgeVersion1}')

# ----- Method 3 -----
msedgeExe = r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
cmdArgs = ["wmic", "DATAFILE", "WHERE", r"NAME='{0}'".format(msedgeExe), "GET", "Version", "/value"]
process = subprocess.check_output(cmdArgs)
edgeVersion3 = re.sub("Version=", "", process.strip().decode())

print(f'Method #3 >>> {edgeVersion3}')
```

Tested with Python 3.8.2 on Windows 10 Version 1909

Hope that helps!

Comment: Interesting, with 
method 1  I get 94.0.992.47  whereas with method 2 & 3   I get 94.0.992.50

Answer (score 0):

> I have to automate getting edge chromium browser version in python.

Do you mean you want to use selenium Edge webdriver to do the automate test? If that is the case, you could refer to [this article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) to download the correct Microsoft WebDriver version for your build of Microsoft Edge, and download a WebDriver language binding of your choice.

Then, use the `driver.capabilities['browserVersion']` command to get the Microsoft Edge Chromium version in python, more detail, please check the following code (remember to change the path to yours):

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

print("*******************")

option = Options()
option.set_capability("useAutomationExtension", "false")  
option.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'E:\webdriver\edgedriver_win64_81_0_416_72\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe', capabilities= option.to_capabilities());
print(driver.capabilities['browserVersion'])
driver.get("https://www.bing.com")

time.sleep(5)
print("*******************")
time.sleep(5)
```

The output:

[image]

Besides, here is another method to use Command Line to get the Edge chromium version, might be it can help you.

You could use the following command to get the Microsoft Edge Chromium Version:

For Microsoft Edge Stable version (using the default setting):

`wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe" get Version /value`

For the Microsoft Edge Dev or Beta version, change the path to yours:

`wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Dev\\Application\\msedge.exe" get Version /value`

The screenshot as below:

[image]