# Use JavaScript before launching browser to get browser version

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I am building a web scraping application using Selenium that will run on Windows desktops.  I can assume the browser (Edge), but not the browser version (e.g. 90 or 91).  I'm using JavaScript for ease of installation.

Before I instantiate Selenium, I need to determine the browser build (e.g. 90.0.818.46) so I can choose a compatible version of the WebDriver.  I can use the amazing command line technique in [how to get microsoft edge chromium version from command line or registry settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863482/how-to-get-microsoft-edge-chromium-version-from-command-line-or-registry-setting).  However, I'd rather do this natively in JavaScript, ideally using the Windows Scripting Host interpreter.  Node.js is also an option.

As described in the StackOverflow post mentioned above, in Python, I can query the registry directly.  E.g.:

```
import winreg

keyPath1 = r"Software\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon"
key1 = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyPath1, 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
edgeVersion1 = winreg.QueryValueEx(key1, "version")[0]
```

Is there an equivalent approach in JavaScript?

I'm new to this so I'm open to other approaches to solve this use case.

Comment: Maybe it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser

Comment: @Michael Rovinsky, this is helpful but if I understand correctly, all the solutions in the post you suggested assume the JavaScript is running in the browser -- i.e. that the ```navigator``` object is available.  I want to determine the browser version before launching Selenium, so I can know what version of Selenium to use.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible

Comment: *"I'd rather do this natively in JavaScript"* - What means "natively" to you?

Comment: @IInspectable By "natively", I mean without running an OS command and collecting the response.  In the Python example I gave, the ```winreg``` package exposes the needed data without an explicit call to the OS.